# Scapy - packet forging issues

Tags: python-3.x, networking, snmp, scapy, icmp

The problems:

1. ICMP: how to fix this warning: [ Expert Info (Warning/Sequence): No response seen to ICMP request]
2. SNMP: how to fix these warnings:

   - [Expert Info (Warning/Malformed): BER Error: Wrong field in SEQUENCE: expected class:UNIVERSAL(0) tag:16(SEQUENCE) but found class:UNIVERSAL(0) tag:4]
   - [BER Error: Wrong field in SEQUENCE: expected class:UNIVERSAL(0) tag:4(OCTET STRING) but found class:CONTEXT(2) tag:2

The story: I'm playing with scapy.

ICMP: I have two tools: A is the sender ( which sends a echo-request ) and B is the recipient ( which sends a echo-reply AFTER it sniffs a echo-request ).
The code of A:

```
 ....
 text = input('')
 pinger = IP(dst=x.x.x.x)/ICMP(id=0x7ccb, seq=1)/text
 send(pinger)
 ....
```

The code of B:

```
 ....
 srg = "x.x.x.x"

 dst = "x.x.x.x"
 textback = "ok"
 sniff(filter=f"src host {srg} and dst host {dst} and icmp", 
 iface="XX", count=1)
 send(IP(dst=x.x.x.x)/ICMP(type="echo-reply", id=0x7ccb, 
 seq=1)/textback)
 ....
```

The result:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtKSD.png)

SNMP: I would like to replicate the same thing of ICMP, but before that I would like to create a non-malformed stuff as wireshark says. The code of how I create the SNMP ( get & response ) datagrams:

```
....
req = IP(dst="x.x.x.x")/UDP()/SNMP(version=3, community="private", 
PDU=SNMPget(varbindlist= 
[SNMPvarbind(oid="1.2.3",value="test")]))
....
res = IP(dst="x.x.x.x")/UDP()/SNMP(version=3, community="private", 
PDU=SNMPresponse(varbindlist= 
[SNMPvarbind(oid="1.2.3",value="test")]))
....
```

The result:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRMI9.png)

Also, does not even get displayed the type of message ( get & response ):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bd14e.png)

Comment: I think you're using SNMPv2c and not 3. By replacing 3 by 2, wireshark display the frames correctly.

Comment: For the ICMP packet could it be that the payload of the reply (`textback`) is different than the payload of the request? (And could you post the full code because it's hard to tell right now?)

Comment: @qouify I tried replacing the version, and yeah, you are right! The frames are displayed correctly. But why? I mean, at least the request should work: https://www.cloudshark.org/captures/1083c13d7b8b. You are right also on the ICMP part! The text must be the same, if not it displays a warning. Is there any way to hide it? I mean: is there any way to avoid that situation even if the payload in the request is different than the one in the reply? ps: I edited the question based on your comment!(:

Comment: SNMPv2c and SNMPv3 packets have totally different structures. The structure you have used only works for v2c.

Comment: @qouify But I used this guide: https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced_usage.html if you scrolldown you will see something similar to my example